# How to enter more than 1 integer in a loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a program that allows the user to select from 4 choices:
1 - Set percentage for grades
2 - Enter grades
3 - Get average
4 - Quit

The program is working smoothly, no compile errors, and I am able to choose each choice and get the line of text to display properly.

My question is, when users select choice 2 to enter grades, how can they enter more than 1 grade without it executing? Currently when you type in a grade, press enter, it will bring you back to the main menu without allowing you to enter more than 1 grade. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseThree
{
public static void main ( String[] argsv )
{

    float percent = 0;
    double grade = 0;
    double totalAvg = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double gradeAvg = 0;

    int gradeCounter = 0;
    int quit;
    int choice = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    while (choice != 4 ) 
    {

    System.out.println( "Please choose one of the following: \n 1 - Set percentage of total for new grades \n 2 - Enter new grades \n 3 - Get average \n 4 - Quit ");
    choice = input.nextInt();



        switch (choice)

        { 

            case 1:         
                System.out.println( "Enter a percentage to multiply by (Format: 10% = .10)" );
                percent = input.nextFloat(); 


            break;



            case 2:
                System.out.println( "Enter grades" );
                grade = input.nextDouble();
                total = total + grade;
                gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
                gradeAvg = (double) total / gradeCounter;

            break;      



            case 3:
                System.out.println( "You have chosen to get the average" );
                totalAvg = totalAvg + percent * grade;
                totalAvg = input.nextDouble();          
            break;



            default: 
                System.out.println( "You have chosen to quit" );

            break; 


        }

    }


}

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving some of this logic to a method...don't try to put it all in `main()`.

Comment: I haven't really learned about multiple methods yet :s

Comment: so how do you want to work on can you please explain a bit

Comment: put the grade getter in a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Make a loop until they enter a stop character (for example a blank character)

```
case 2:
            System.out.println( "Enter grades" );
            boolean isDone = false;
            while(isDone == false) {
               grade = input.nextDouble();
               if(grade == '') {
                  isDone = true;
                }
            }
            total = total + grade;
            gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
            gradeAvg = (double) total / gradeCounter;
```

Comment: But doubles can be compared to charactars. what about a negative grade?

Comment: This answer is incomplete though - You must store these values in a list. Also, I would maybe ask for string input(instead of nextDouble) and do conversions to double if it's not a blank character.

Answer (score 1):

```
            System.out.print("How Many Grades You Enter");
            int s=input.nextInt();
            while(s>0)
            {           
            System.out.println( "Enter grades" );
            grade = input.nextDouble();
            total = total + grade;
            gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
            gradeAvg = (double) total / gradeCounter;
            s--;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a while loop in the case-block?

```
while (gradCounter < 4) {
     System.out.println( "Enter grades" );
     grade = input.nextDouble();
     total = total + grade;
     gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
     gradeAvg = (double) total / gradeCounter;
}
```